# Find row that contains inputted string using CSV module in Python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I am trying to get all of the contents of the line that matches the "profile_name" I input
here is the CSV layout:

```
    profile_name,first_name,last_name,age
```

here is the information:

```
    Johnny,Johnny,Appleseed,25
```

i have tried many things, but i do not understand the CSV module.
Any clarification / help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csv module would allow you to get each line in the file as a list of columns.

You can then search for the value in the column you expect it to be.

Something along these lines:

```
import csv

# wait for user to input the profile to search
profile_to_search = input()

with open('profiles.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if profile_to_search == row[0]:
            print row
```